# Firebase/nodeJS - fetch data from multiple firebase data reference

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a json api that gets data from reference, then using an ID inside the reference data I need to get other data from another reference and put them all in object.

1. [first reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYvTi.png)
2. [second reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYreT.png)

I want to get the data from the first reference and use dUid to get the email from the second reference. 
The problem is the async calls, I can't just get the data from one table and wait for the other to finish and I can't get all the data from the first ref and then from the second because i send my response in a call back of one of the references like this:

```
app.get('/trip-statistics', (request, response) => {
   tripRef.once('value').then(
     snap => response.status(200).send(extractTripInfo(snap))
   );
});
```

Comment: https://youtu.be/NgZIb6Uwpjc - Check this video which explains your problem precisely

Answer (score 1):

Node 8 has support for the async/await syntax which should make this fairly easy:

```js
// Note the `async` keyword in front of the function
app.get('/trip-statistics', async (request, response) => {

  // we'll wait for the first promise, its value will be put into the `tripValue` variable
  const trip = await tripRef.once('value').then(snap => snap.val())

  // whenever the trip is resolved, we will create a new promise, which depends on `trip.dUid`
  const driver = await driverRef.child(trip.dUid).once('value').then(snap => snap.val())

  // when both promises are fulfilled, we can tell the response to send both objects
  response.status(200).send({ trip, driver })
})
```

Don't forget to catch errors, you can find some examples in [this article](https://medium.com/@Abazhenov/using-async-await-in-express-with-node-8-b8af872c0016).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using nested .them statements

```
app.get('/trip-statistics')
    .then(request, response) => {
    // add stuff from url1 response to url2
    return app.get('/driver'+ response.data[0].id)
  })
  .then(request, response) => {
    // add stuff from url2 response to url3
    return rp(url3)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log)
```